# GeoServer Issues

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, gis, geoserver

While running the server, I am unable to view the layers in GeoServer. I checked the `Enabled` checkbox, and still I am unable to view the map.
If I login once again into GeoServer, the `Enabled` checkbox is unchecked.
The below error which I got in logs after starting the Apache Tomcat Server:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
>
> Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
>
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
>
> ERROR [geotools.jdbc] - There's code using JDBC based datastore and not disposing them. This may lead to temporary loss of database connections. Please make sure all data access code calls DataStore.dispose() before freeing all references to it.

Comment: You are trying to connect to your database as user "postgres" and either the password is incorrect or password authentication is not enabled for "postgres" in the pg_hba.conf file. See manuals for details.

Comment: Actually, the application is working fine in server.and by accessing through the server URl also, it is working fine in my machine....The problem which iam facing is. When iam deploying and running same code through eclipse in my machine.. Previously it is working fine in my localhost. But suddenly, i got this problem

Comment: If it's "suddenly" then something has changed. What? In any case, as my comment says the error is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one thing that can cause this suddenly is password expiration in PostgreSQL, though this is not typical.  Most likely the password changed on one of the sides, so check that first.

PostgreSQL allows you to specify that a password expires at a specific timestamp.  So you can:

```
 ALTER USER foo WITH PASSWORD 'bar' VALID UNTIL 'tomorrow';
```

And foo will be able to log in with the password 'bar' until the next day at system time....

So if you can verify that the password did not change on both sides, try this:

```
ALTER USER foo WITH VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

Of course substitute your real user for `foo`.    This will clear any expiration, or rather move the expiration time indefinitely into the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is likely to be that the postgres user is configured to only accept logins from the local machine. You will need to configure it to accept logins from the machine name or ip address you are logining in from or even better create a new user that has only the required permissions to login rather than using the deffault admin postgres user. Even if you are on the same machine using eclipse may be making it look as though you are coming from a different machine depending on your configuration.

Please see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html) and [here](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1237/How+do+I+enable+remote+access+to+my+PostgreSQL+server?#dv) about configuring this type of access